# proof that a bounded sequence has a subsequence converging to its greatest lower bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I need help with the following:

> (Abbot 2nd edition 2.5.) Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence. Let $S = \{x \in R: x<a_n \text{for infinite many a_n} \}$. Show that there exists a subsequence of $a_n$ converging to $sup(S)$

I assume this is equivalent to showing that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  inf(a_n)$ exists and there is a subsequence converging to it.

This is what I tried:

> Given $A_n=\{a_m, m>=n\}$, we use the sequence $b_n = inf(A_n)$, which exist by the Axiom of Completeness, since $A_n$ is bounded. Since $A_{n-1}\supset A_n \Rightarrow b_{n-1}>= b_n$. Therefore $b_n$ is monotone. Since it is also bounded, it converges to some value $b$

> Let $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary. Choose $N$ such that $n>N \Rightarrow |b_n-b|<\epsilon/2$. For any $n$, there exists $a_{m>=n}$ such that $a_m<b_n+\epsilon/2$, otherwise $b_n+\epsilon/2>b_n$ would be a lower bound.

> Therefore $\begin{cases}
> a_m<b_n+\epsilon/2<b+\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2<b+\epsilon\\
> a_m>b_n>b-\epsilon/2>b-\epsilon
> \end{cases}
> \Rightarrow |a_m-b|<\epsilon
> $

I am pretty confident of these steps. What I am not sure is if the fact that we can find $a_m \rightarrow b$ constitutes proof enough that we can build a subsequence out of this. Can this be done?